# Synonym for 'reinforce/back up idea/concept'

Tags: synonyms

I'm sure there must be a word for this! I'm looking for a synonym for 'reinforce/back up idea/concept'. Eg: "He looks like an Australian and his accent would seem to back that up/suggest likewise/reinforce that notion." Any ideas for a synonym? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried looking for synonyms by googling etc.?  What have you found already? There are plenty, including "**support**".

Comment: _reinforce, support, give credence to, add/provide more evidence for, ..._  It's a matter of metaphor. If you're using a construction theme, _reinforce, provide grounding, shore up the foundation, ..._ If you're using a visual metaphor, _makes it look more like, uncovers more evidence, ..._ Et cetera.

Answer (score 2):

He looks like an Australian and his accent would seem to **confirm** that.

Though I'm not sure I know what an Australian "looks like", that's any different to countless other nationalities.